# Dispatch an array on twice the number of items

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I made a memory game for the train, and I have some problems

I have a painting with four pictures and eight cards.
How do I send the four pictures on the eight cards?

Knowing that each image should be sent twice, but not consecutively?

- Each card represents a design
- All cards are in double
- There can not be 3 times the same pictures

Here is my code :

JS :

```js
// RULES
var rules = {
   "level":{
     "1":{
      "numberOfCard": 8,
      "time": false,
      "life": false
     },
     "2":{
      "numberOfCard": 16,
      "time": false,
      "life": false
     },
     "3":{
      "numberOfCard": 16,
      "time": 120,
      "life": false
     },
     "4":{
      "numberOfCard": 16,
      "time": 120,
      "life": 16
     }
    }
   }

var pictures = ["http://i.imgur.com/TA0OiA2.jpg", "http://i.imgur.com/sjtxLQM.jpg", "http://i.imgur.com/rYqnVSn.jpg", "http://i.imgur.com/E2XwA5s.jpg"];

$(document).ready(function() {
 
 // Instanciation d'un objet game
 game = new Board(rules);
 $(".square").click(function(){
  let card = game.flipCard( $(this) ); 
  console.log(card);
 });
 
});

class Board{
 
 //On object creation
 constructor(){
  let stage = 1;
  this.rules = rules;
  this.initialisation(stage);
 }
 
 initialisation(stage){
  this.generateBoard(rules.level[stage].numberOfCard);
  // Do something after generating the board
 }
 
 shuffleBoard(listOfCards){
  for(let i = 0; i<listOfCards.length; i++){
   // Génère un nombre entre 0 et la longueur de l'array -1
   let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * listOfCards.length);
   
   //Puis intervertis les valeurs
   [listOfCards[i], listOfCards[random]] = [listOfCards[random], listOfCards[i]];
  }
  return listOfCards;
 }
 
 generateBoard(numberOfCards){
  // Crée un array du nombre de carte
  var listOfCards = [];
  
  // Qu'on remplis du nombre de carte nécessaire
  for(let i = 0; i<numberOfCards; i++){
   let id = i+1;
   listOfCards.push(id);
  }
  
  // Puis on l'envois à la fonction shuffle pour le mélange, qui retournera un array mélangé 
  let finalStack = this.shuffleBoard(listOfCards);
  // Enfin on génère les cartes selon l'array reçu
  var html ="";
  for(let i = 0; i<finalStack.length; i++){
   html += "<div class='square square-" + finalStack[i] + "'>";
    //html += "<img src='http://i.imgur.com/TA0OiA2.jpg' alt='' />";
   html += "</div>";
  }
  $(".wrapper").html(html);
 }

 flipCard(card){
  card.addClass('flip');
  return card.attr('class');
 }
}
```

```css
body, 
.wrapper{
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
}

body{
 height: 100vh;
 justify-content: center; 
}

.wrapper{
 width: 480px;
    background: grey;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 60px;
}

.square{
 width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 9px 0;
    background: green;
 transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.flip{
 transform: rotateY(-180deg);
 background: red;
}

img {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body id="board">
<section class="wrapper"></section>
</body>
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Could you edit your question and add your code?

Comment: drawings=drawings.concat(drawings); then shuffle and display

Comment: Code edited, sorry for the mix french / english in comment :o